# External hard drive won't mount

Tags: 10.04, mount

Since plugging the hard drive in didn't automatically make a window pop up I decided to manually mount the hard drive in Disk Utility. It gives me this:

```
Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
mount: according to mtab, /dev/sdb1 is already mounted on /
mount failed
```

Could this have been caused by leaving the hard drive plugged in when shutting down?

`/etc/mtab`:

```
/dev/sdb1 / ext4 rw,errors=remount-ro,commit=0 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /sys sysfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw 0 0
none /dev devtmpfs rw,mode=0755 0 0
none /dev/pts devpts rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620 0 0
none /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /var/run tmpfs rw,nosuid,mode=0755 0 0
none /var/lock tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /lib/init/rw tmpfs rw,nosuid,mode=0755 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
gvfs-fuse-daemon /home/matthew/.gvfs fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon rw,nosuid,nodev,user=matthew 0 0
```

`/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/sda1       /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=3b0db205-2bdb-4c98-a506-6bdd3520d540 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Could you please show us the contents of your `/etc/mtab` and `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: And /proc/mounts as i shows what is currently mounted.

Comment: Sorry... Here you go.

Answer (score 3):

[here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB) is ubuntu help page for mounting usb drives. I have an external hardrive which has 2 ntfs and 1 ext3 partition I have entered the configuration on /etc/fstab so that it mounts on boot time. You can do this if you do not usually move your external drive. There is another mounting utility for automount, you can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install usbmount
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a lot of data on your disk I might just format/partition it and then set up a new directory to mount it to using terminal. Then you could either manually mount it or have it automatically mounted on start up. [**This page**](http://www.ubuntulinuxguide.com/hard-disk-partition) will show you how to format/partition and mount.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:-

You can change it manually, by changing your `/` partition entry to it's actual device name.

Find your `/` partition's actual device (eg. in my case `/dev/sdb1`)

Press ALT + F2 Type `gksudo gedit` Open up `/etc/fstab`.

Change your root partition to the device listed in "Disk Utility". Restart your computer, and enjoy

In my case I changed `/etc/fstab` Entry

```
/dev/sda1 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

to this

```
"/dev/sdb1 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1"
```

Read about '[MTAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mtab)' & '[FSTAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab)' in wikipedia for more clarity... Quite nicely explained there...Thanks 2 all you guys @ Wikipedia.