# Can't access an ext4 partition in a external HD

Tags: external-hdd, ext4

I have a 1TB external HD that I partitioned into a FAT32 partition and an ext4 partition. Apparently the file system of the ext4 is damaged and I cannot access it. The disk utility on the drive looks like this:
[image: screenshot]

I though I could use this answer: [External hard drive won't mount](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4368/external-hard-drive-wont-mount-how-to-troubleshoot), but as you can see, for some reason I do not have the option to check the partition. BTW, formatting is not an option for me if there is a way to recover most of the files.

Output of `mount`:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/rafael/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=rafael)
/dev/sdb2 on /media/WIN32 type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks)
```

Output of `more /etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=f27f4656-379e-4500-af22-ec76b871b657 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=294dddf0-2c87-4339-8f16-b0028a6ec232 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try running the filesystem check from a terminal:

```
sudo e2fsck -y -v /dev/sdb1
```

However, if the filesystem is damaged beyond repair, the last option to recover files is [testdisk](http://www.howtoforge.com/data_recovery_with_testdisk).

Comment: Glad that you have. Did you have to use testdisk?

Comment: No, the command with `e2fsck` was sufficient.